# CKeditor4 superscript, subscript

Tags: ckeditor4.x

I have CKeditor4.3.1 and have buttons for superscript and subscript
[image: buttons]

You can see them and they work on edit area, but it doesn't on site's page
[image: page]

Code on a page have this tags

```
   <m:omath>
        <m:ssub>
            <m:ssubpr>
                <m:ctrlpr></m:ctrlpr>
            </m:ssubpr>
            <m:sub>
                <m:r>
                    <m:rpr>
                        <m:scr m:val="roman">
                            <m:sty m:val="b"></m:sty>
                        </m:scr>
                    </m:rpr>
                    <span style="font-size:14px;"><sub>t</sub></span></m:r>
                <m:r>
                    <m:rpr>
                        <m:scr m:val="roman">
                            <m:sty m:val="b"></m:sty>
                        </m:scr>
                    </m:rpr>
                    <span style="font-size:14px;"><sub>+</sub></span></m:r>
                <m:r>
                    <m:rpr>
                        <m:scr m:val="roman">
                            <m:sty m:val="b"></m:sty>
                        </m:scr>
                    </m:rpr>
                    <span style="font-size:14px;"><sub>1</sub></span></m:r>
            </m:sub>
        </m:ssub>
    </m:omath>
```

May be I miss some styles or plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Okey, sorry. It was reset.css, who re-styled sup and sub styles. Just removed them from css file and it works now.